# How to call validator from request class in controller method? Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I need to use validation in these two methods:

```
public function store(ResourceRequest $request)
{
    $page = new Page();
    $page->create([
        'content'     => request('content'),
        'title'       => request('title'),
        'slug'        => $this->metadataHandler->generateSlug(request('slug')),
        // etc.
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('pages');
}

public function update(ResourceRequest $request, Page $page)
{
    $page->update([
        'content'     => request('content'),
        'title'       => request('title'),
        'slug'        => $this->metadataHandler->generateSlug(request('slug')),
        // etc.
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('pages');
}
```

But I see no place, where I can call variable `$request`. The variable is declared in method argument, and remains not used. I can't just write `$request->all()`, because I need to apply different handler methods to some input fields.

And also, I repeating myself in this fields list. It's the same in both methods. Any tips, how to avoid duplication?

Comment: use request object rather using helper function and your own code will be fine like $request->content not request('content'). and you can write $request->all();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a helper function i.e. `request()` instead you could use the following:

```
# Helper function    # $request object
request('content') = $request->content
request('title') = $request->title
```

You can make it shorter like:

```
public function store(ResourceRequest $request)
{
    $page = new Page();
    $page->create($request->except('_token'));
    return redirect()->route('pages');
}
```

And you can use generateSlug() in the Page model by defining an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).

```
class Pageextends Model
{
    public function getSlugAttribute($value)
    {
        // Use meta data handler here $this->metadataHandler->generateSlug
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not `getAttribute`, but `setAttribute`? Method `generateSlug` checks, if field is empty, and if yes - it generates it from timestamp. I did this `$this->attributes['slug'] = $this->metadataHandler->generateSlug($value);` in model method `setSlugAttribute`, and I have an error: Call to a member function generateSlug() on null

Comment: @Famaxis The error is because of `$this->metadataHandler`. Here `$this` means the **metadataHandler** belongs to the model. Its better to make an Repository or Service to handle the metadata handler and inject it to anywhere like Classes, Models etc.

Comment: It's a service, and I called it in model with `__construct()` method. Screenshot -https://iili.io/f1DBEJ.png

Comment: Update: I made method `generateSlug()` static, and it works now. But what if I need to pass two or more arguments in 'setAttribute()' method? For example, I want to check field 'slug' itself, and if it's empty, then check 'title' field to generate slug from it. And if 'title' is empty too, maybe there is another field I want to check. Can mutators work with it?